# how to combine two text in one array

Tags: python

```
vowels=["a","e","i","o","u"]
word=["a","ir","the","book"]
for i in word:
    if len(i) == 1 and i in vowels:
        ....
```

I just make this loop to detect 'a' in 'vowels' array and have only one space

like 'a' = 1 space , 'ant' = 3 spaces.

I want to combine 'a' with the following word in array.

how can I combine 'a' with 'ir' to make 'word' array to be

```
word=["air","the","book"]
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}  # used set for efficient `in` operation
>>> words = ['a', 'ir', 'the', 'book']
>>> for i in range(len(words) - 2, -1, -1):
...     if words[i] in vowels:
...         # len(words[i]) == 1 is redundant (all vowels items' length = 1)
...         words[i] += words.pop(i + 1)  # merge vowel with next word
... 
>>> words
['air', 'the', 'book']
```

NOTE: iterated backward; otherwise indexes are broken as soon as `list.pop` called.

Comment: @AChampion, I came up with a similar solution with yours (`iter + next`), but I had an issue with a case: `word = ['banan', 'a']`. You could write `next(iterable, '')` to address StopIteration issue.

Comment: @AChampion, There is a case where your solution and mine disagree: `word = ['a', 'i', 'r']`

Comment: Indeed, unclear from OP's example if this is something they need to account for. Though a simple recursive helper function to do the `concat` would make it functionally equivalent.

Comment: @AChampion, I came up with [this](http://ideone.com/l9WC98) initially, trying to use `itertools.takewhile` instead of recursion; found out that `takewhile` abandon non-matching item. posted this answer :|

Comment: what is -2, -1, -1) ?

Comment: @kouty, `len(words) - 2`, not `-2`: index pointing the second to the last item. starting index.

Comment: @kouty, last -1: step, yielded `i` are decreasing by 1 (increasing by -1). `-1` in the middle: stop index. `range` will stop yielding on `-1` (not yield -1 itself).

Comment: @kouty, So, if length of `words` is 4: `range(len(words)-2, -1, -1)` will yields 2, 1, 0. In other word, indexes of words reversed words (excluding the last word)

Comment: @falsetru, I also briefly considered `takewhile` but recalled it discarded. So ultimately a similar result. The advantage of the `iterable` approach is it also works on iterables :)

Comment: @falsetru Perfect

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iterator to construct the new list, just add the `next()` item if the current item is `in vowels`, e.g.:

```
>>> vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
>>> words = ["a", "ir", "the", "book"]
>>> iterable = iter(word)
>>> [i+next(iterable, '') if i in vowels else i for i in iterable]
['air', 'the', 'book']
```

Or if you happen to need to add multiple vowels:

```
def concat(i, iterable):
    return i + concat(next(iterable, ''), iterable) if i in vowels else i

>>> words = ['a', 'i', 'r']
>>> iterable = iter(words)
>>> [concat(i, iterable) for i in iterable]
['air']
```